# Secure Erase equivalent for an SD card?

Tags: sd-card

SATA devices and NVMe devices support Secure Erase where such a command can be issued [like this](https://ata.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ATA_Secure_Erase) in the case of supported ATA devices. But I can't seem to find anything about how to erase an SD card in such a manner.

Is there a way to wipe the drive at a firmware level (perhaps some equivalent of Secure Erase or trim)? Or is the only way `dd if=/dev/urandom of=[DISK]` or some similar overwrite?

Thanks!

Comment: If there is, it'll likely depend on the OS whether you'll be able to actually issue that command to the card. Windows or Linux or a BSD? Is the reader USB-attached or PCI-attached?

Comment: @grawity either Windows or Linux (have access to both) and it's USB attached.

Comment: Maybe check out this question? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/599977/20336